# Java - Thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x95d40b20)

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, crash

While I was deploying I got this problem:

```
9389-9389/com.example.yashpal.greatdealindia I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 3.100MB for 281892-byte allocation
02-18 15:01:50.875    9389-9398/com.example.yashpal.greatdealindia D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 22% free 3143K/4004K, paused 1100ms, total 1100ms
02-18 15:01:50.905    9389-9389/com.example.yashpal.greatdealindia D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-18 15:01:50.905    9389-9389/com.example.yashpal.greatdealindia W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x95d40b20)
```

How shall I solve this?

Manifest.xml :

```
 <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" 
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" 
android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
tools:ignore="NewApi">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <categoryandroid:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Expandabl‌emain"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"> 
</activity>
```

Comment: Please post the code of your main activity. You're probably doing something wrong in there.

Answer (score 0):

remove metadata from **activity** and place it under **application** like this:

```
<application>
  <metadata .... />
  <activity .... />
</application>
```